# Getting Button location on Screen

Tags: android, android-button

I have created a dynamic button and Added it to LinearLayout, parent view of the Linear layout is HorizontalScrollView.
I need to move the scroll position of the Horozontal scollview dynamically.

I am unable to get the Button location on screen. It is always giving [0,0] for the Button Y and Y Location on screen.

My XML file :

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/imv_Line_Invisibe"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imv_logo"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_but"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Adding the button to dynamically to linear layout:

```
    int i = 0;
    for (HashMap<String, String> map : category)
        for (Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
            String strButLabel = mapEntry.getValue();
            Log.i("map", "" + strButLabel);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;
            String value = mapEntry.getValue();
            TextView tvSetID = new TextView(this);
            tvSetID.setId(i);
            butCategory = new Button(this);
            butCategory.setId(i);
            butCategory.setText(value);
            butCategory.setTextSize(13);
            butCategory.setAllCaps(true);
            butCategory.setLayoutParams(params);
            butCategory.setTypeface(custom_font, Typeface.BOLD);
            butCategory.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
            butCategory.setPadding(0, 0, 20, 20);
            butCategory.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nav_phone_unselect);
            butCategory.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
            butCategory.setOnClickListener(OnClickChangeButtonColor(butCategory));
            i++;
        }
```

This is the code I am using for getting the location of the Button on screen:

```
int temp_index = intent.getIntExtra("btn_index_value", 0);
Button butCategory = (Button) findViewById(temp_index);
butCategory.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nav_phone_select);
butCategory.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
String i1 = butCategory.getText().toString();
int[] locations = new int[2];
butCategory.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
int x = locations[0];
int y = locations[1];
horizontal_Category.scrollTo(x, y);
index = temp_index;
```

Comment: You can Use View.getX() & View.getY() to get x&y coordinates respect to pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this - View.getLocationOnScreen() and/or getLocationInWindow().